# Parenting or ChildOf

Tags: parent

I'm confused a little bit. I think the CTRL+P and ChildOf constraint quite same thing. But .... 
So please anybody explain what is the main difference or behaviuors between the two approach. Sometimes I recognised differences but I can't define exactly why.

Comment: I would say it's the same except with Child Of constraint you can put keyframes on Influence or visibility so you can start or stop the parentage whenever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to have a ChildOf constraint is for cases where you need to change parenting during animation. Like when a character needs to grab an item, or throw it- at the moment this happens, you can animate the constraint influence and be able to animate the object properly.

You should use normal parenting for everything else, because this method is far simpler, and simply more correct. The hierarchy is visible in Outliner, mostly exporters will work with it e.t.c.

Comment: .. also, Child Of allows you to select _which_ transforms are inherited, and which not.